# How to implement Splash Screen and go to MainActivity from it properly rendered

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

### My question is about how to make splash screen, and finish the splash screen if the `MainActivity` done rendered, not by timeout set.

I have been searched how to make splash screen and i have done it, but mainly they are using `timeout` to set when the splash screen have to closed/finish.

What i want is how to finish the splash screen when the `MainActivity` completely rendered, not after how many seconds to close the splash screen.

Is there any way to get something like `render completed` state?

---

I tried to code the `finishSplashScreen()` in the `onResume()` and worked as i want, but the problem is, its always trigger the `finishSplashScreen()` when you reopenning the `MainActivity` whereas i just want to trigger that function only one time when the app is openned.

Is there any way to make what i want?

---

### Update

> I found what i need, this tricks simply useful.
>
> http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Comment: Because Splashscreen comes first and then your main activity , do not  load the main activity until unless all the background activity needed for main  activity is completed. Load it only after all the resources needed for main activity are available.

Comment: Why don't you just remember if it is the first time or not?

Comment: thanks for all, i found the tricks what i need.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been searched how to make splash screen and i have done it, but mainly they are using timeout to set when the splash screen have to closed/finish.

Then you probably have not done it right.
Hard to tell without seeing your code obviously, however this link can most likely provide you guidance on how to build a proper SplashScreen :

https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857

No timeout, just a very fast-loading SplashScreen (no setContentView, only theming), and the only responsibility of this SplashScreen being to launch your MainActivity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the better tricks like what i need. updated in my question.